# Como fazer uma data em formato ISO 8601 mas ser na mesma um DateTime

Tags: c#, data

Eu queria saber como é que posso transformar um DateTime em um formato ISO 8601 mas manter em um tipo de DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é uma forma de representação da data. Um `DateTime` é uma estrutura que tenta simular um ponto no tempo (uma data), como você vai representá-la data não é trabalho desta estrutura em si.

Você pode usar um `.ToString("o")` para representar um `DateTime` no formato ISO 8601.

```
string dataFormatada = minhaData.ToString("o");
```

[Veja um exemplo funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNdENX)

Comment: mas assim não vai ficar em string?

Comment: Jovem, **um `DateTime` não tem formato**. Ele é uma estrutura, você formata para mostrar, para serializar, alguma coisa assim.

Comment: Exacto mas não há possibilidade de manter em DateTime ?

Comment: Não, cara. Um DateTime **não tem formato**. Você vai formatar quando precisar.

Comment: Como eu faço para num  httpWebRequest.Date dizer que a data tem de ter essa formatação ?

Comment: Isso é um header que é enviado na requisição. Ele é formatado com um formato específico ([vide documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.date(v=vs.110).aspx): `The classes in the System.Net namespace always write it out the Date property on the wire during transmission in standard form using GMT (Utc) format.`). Então, se você quer enviar este header de forma diferente, adicione-o manualmente com o formato que você pretende usar.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso ?

Comment: Claro. A sua dúvida dessa pergunta foi respondida, né? Abra uma nova pergunta com a outra dúvida específica.